# React js simple hook effect

Tags: reactjs

Having the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function UseEffectComp1() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {    
        if (mounted)
            setMounted(false);
        else
            setMounted(true);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button onClick={() => {
                    mounted ? console.log("mounted") : console.log("not mounted");
                }
                }>
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export {UseEffectComp1}
```

I'm getting the infinite loop problem.
What's wrong with it an how to make it works?

Comment: Answer of @Liu is correct, but what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {    
  if (mounted)
    setMounted(false);
  else
    setMounted(true);
},[]);
```

the reason is because every time when you call `setMounted` `useEffect` will be called. so the value of `mounted` changing between `true` and `false`. therefore you getting the infinite loop problem